# How to use 'User entering list" in python while writing a code in a **non-interactive environment**?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I want to know how can we use a "user entering list" in Python while writing a code in a **non-interactive environment**?

For example... In the case of string we do following:-

```
str1=input("Enter the string1: ")
```

Similarly for integers we type following lines while writing a code.

```
num1=int(input("Enter the number1:"))
```

Similarly for complex numbers we type following lines while writing a code.

```
c1=complex(input("Enter complex number1: "))
```

Please help and also provide answers for tuples as well as dictionary. What is the syntax?

Comment: If you want a user to enter a "list" just have them enter the item(s) separated by `,`'s or some other delimiter and you can use `split` as one option. You can do the same for a tuple but just put the `split` inside of `tuple`. You'll have to handle types of course if you want them to be ints strings etc

Comment: Somebody's inevitably going to suggest `eval`. This is a bad idea; it has messy results when the user does something wrong and possibly catastrophic results when the user does something malicious, and it sidesteps the important task of learning how to parse inputs that don't directly map to Python syntax.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: I like using `iter` with a `sentinal_value`

Comment: I was interested to know that is there any syntax for entering the list in a code (in a non interactive mode). As for integers/complex numbers/strings there is a syntax which I have mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to *safely* evaluate any python literal from the user:

```
import ast

data = ast.literal_eval(input("enter a python literal:"))
print(type(data),data)
```

this lets you type in all kinds of things:

```
enter a python literal:[1,2,3]
<class 'list'> [1, 2, 3]
enter a python literal:(3,2,1)
<class 'tuple'> (3, 2, 1)
enter a python literal:"hello"
<class 'str'> hello
enter a python literal:3.4
<class 'float'> 3.4

#this one is *extremely* malicious when put in eval()
enter a python literal:open(__file__,"w").close()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x1056b4f98>

# but ast.literal_eval is safe with user input like this.
```

although you might as well just [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the data by commas to get a list:

```
data = input("enter some values seperated by ,s: ").split(",")
```

this will give you a list:

```
enter some values seperated by ,s: 1,2,3
<class 'list'> ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of this as the user entering a list. The user entering a list is like your boss firing your neurons manually; a list is a program-internal data structure that the user should not be dealing with.

Define a format for user input and write appropriate format-dependent code to parse it. For example, if you want your user to input base-10 integers, separated by commas and (optionally) whitespace, you could use

```
ints = [int(s) for s in input().split(',')]
```

If you really want your input format to be Python literal syntax, you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
obj = ast.literal_eval(input())
```

And if you see nothing wrong with the idea of your boss firing your neurons manually, you can have the user input arbitrary Python expressions (not statements) with `eval`. **This is almost never a good idea**:

```
# Bad idea - this makes a mess if the user does something wrong and is potentially
# catastrophic if the user does something malicious.
# For example, if the user types __import__('os').system('nasty command'),
# they can delete all your files or steal your browser's saved passwords.
terrible_idea = eval(input())
```

Comment: `open(__file__,"w").close()` is a valid python expression, if `eval`uated it will delete the contents .py file currently being executed. However it is not a valid _literal_ so ast is still safe.

Comment: As everyone else said, do NOT give a hint of `eval()` to a obvious beginner of programming/python - without a big disclaimer in well lit text about the issues that can occur with eval and user input! Meaning explain why eval is evil and make it clean that it's a super stupid thing to do unless you know why you need to resort to it. We are helping the world to come here, leave a good lesson if a beginner is asking a question so we don't have to deal with stupid questions from the next generation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've already made it clear that it's a bad idea, plus my comment above, but sure. Answer updated with more elaboration on why it's a bad idea, and bold text for emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

The user can input **only** `str`. Which is to mean that `input()` returns `str`. If you want `list`, you gotta make it a `list`. The same holds for everything else.

```
x = input("a, b, c: ")
# a, b, c: 2,3,4 => x -> "a,b,c" str
l = [int(i.strip()) for i in x.split(",")] # [2, 3, 4]
```

If you would rather have them input `repr()` of what you want, then (**better not to do this way**)

```
x = eval(input("a, b, c: "))
# a, b, c: 2,3,4 => x -> (2, 3, 4) tuple
```

Comment: using eval you can type in `open(__file__,"w").close()` and the user will literally delete the contents of the .py file, please do not use `eval`.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Agreed. Just to show that it works. I will _never_ use `eval()` in any form in the given context.

Comment: then why aren't you suggesting [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) as it only parses python _literals_ not generic expressions.

Comment: As everyone else said, do NOT give a hint of `eval()` to a obvious beginner of programming/python - without a big disclaimer in well lit text about the issues that can occur with eval and user input!